# Running Laravel 5 like a normal browser from command line "php index.php ..." without using Artisan CLI

Tags: php, laravel, command-line, console, command-line-interface

I've been Googling around and haven't been able to find a solution for this.  Basically, I want to run Laravel from the command line WITHOUT using Artisan.  I want to simply open up as if I opened it on a browser.

I tried to do this:

```
php index.php some/route/here
```

Of course, the above is not working.  What I'm expecting is to get some `<html>` stuff as a response, as if I opened it on a browser.

If anyone can advise that would be great!

Comment: can't you use curl?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Curl is a bit different, because that's not a CLI.  I want to make the run internal using the most basic "php" command if that is possible in any way?

Comment: As a matter of fact, a normal php index.php works for me. However, I am quite sceptic about trying to get a specific route because we don't have any server variable that way

Comment: Just making sure you are aware, curl can be used in a CLI to do exactly what you are asking...  `curl yourwebsite.com`

Comment: Curl sounds like an extra wrapper on top of calling "php" to me.  (Hope I'm right about this).  If I'm correct, then there's gotta be a "php" command to do this I guess?  Though I'm not sure, please let me know if I'm completely misunderstanding this.